# How to isolate for X

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This has me bothered a bit and I think I'm missing something obvious here. Trying to isolate this equation for $x$:

$$
\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}  \sqrt{3}x= y
$$

The solution is listed as this:

$$
x = \frac{2y}{1+\sqrt{3}}
$$

If I remove the $1/2$ from the original formula I get this:

$$
x + \sqrt{3}x = 2y
$$

From here it should be simple but I just can't see how the formula can be reduced to the proposed solution. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to isolate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x+\sqrt3 x = x(1+\sqrt3) = 2y$

So,

$x = \frac{2y}{1+\sqrt3}$

Answer (score 1):

It is $$0.5x+0.5\sqrt{3}x=y$$ and by multiplying by $2$ and dividing by $$1+\sqrt{3}$$ we get

$$x=\frac{2y}{1+\sqrt{3}}$$